# How do I pass an img tag its href value through a Go template successfully?

Tags: go, go-html-template

I am attempting to build a page on a personal website to display a series of posts. The post content is stored in a JSON file so I am reading it, and then ranging over the result using Go to inject the values of each 'post' into an HTML template.

My templates look like:

```
{{define "post"}}
<div>
    <div class="post-header">
        <h1>{{.Title}}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="post-image">
        <img href="/static/img/content/{{.ImageRef}}"/>
        <p>{{.ImageCaption}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="post-body">
        {{.Text}}
    </div>

    <div class="post-footer">
        <p>Published: {{.Created}}</p>
    </div>

</div>
{{end}}
```

and

```
{{define "main"}}
 <h2>All Posts</h2>
 <p>posts will go here</p>


 {{range .Posts}}    
    {{template "post" .}}
 {{end}}
{{end}}
```

Currently the template successfully receives the data from the parsed JSON, and even interpolates the correct value into the `href` property (viewed though Chrome inspector); however, the image does not display at all (the tag is present with the correct `href` but has a 0x0 size).

I would like to fix this so that I can dynamically pass part of the URL of various images from my fileserver to posts and have them correctly render the image.

My Go code:

```
func (app *application) handlePosts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

//initialise a slice containing all templates we want to load
files := []string{
    "./ui/html/pages/base.tmpl.html",
    "./ui/html/pages/posts.tmpl.html",
    "./ui/html/partials/post.tmpl.html",
    "./ui/html/partials/nav.tmpl.html",
}

posts_json, err := os.Open("./content/posts/test_posts.json")
if err != nil {
    app.serverError(w, err)
    return
}
defer posts_json.Close()

read, err := io.ReadAll(posts_json)
if err != nil {
    app.serverError(w, err)
    return
}

var posts models.Posts
if err := json.Unmarshal(read, &posts); err != nil {
    app.serverError(w, err)
    return
}

// Parse html template.
ts, err := template.ParseFiles(files...)
if err != nil {
    app.serverError(w, err)
    return
}

// Execute template.
if err = ts.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", posts); err != nil {
    app.serverError(w, err)
    return
}
}
```

Edit: Further I should mention I saw in other questions that it could have to do with passing URLs to templates and that not being safe. Originally I was passing the entire URL for an image but switched to only the postfix like in the example above; while cleaner, this did not fix the issue. I also tried changing the type of the field containing the ref to `template.URL` so that un-marshalled data is already in the correct format, however that had no effect either.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: i'll remove the image

Comment: If the href is correct when viewed in the browser inspector, then the likely problem is that the server responded with a not found response for the href path.

Comment: that's the confusing thing unfortunately, there was no 404 response. To give a little more clarity, I'm hosting the images in my /static/ fileserver where I am also hosting the favicon and an empty JS file, both of which are being successfully retrieved using identical syntax to what is in the href.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat embarrassing but perhaps others might make the same mistake! My intention was to link an image in my static fileserver to an `<img>` tag to render on a web page.

I mistakenly used the `href` property instead of `src` which is why it wasn't working as the URL lead to a `.png` file, not valid HTML.